# Running a Zend Framework based Project on Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework

Currently I try to get PHP and Zend working on Eclipse. I'm not sure if there is a plugin for Zend or something that makes it comfortable to use in Eclipse, like automatically initializing default MVC-pattern like directory structure, and so on...

I was googling for it and found some tools... First I tried to download and install the PDT from Zend (http://www.zend.com/en/company/community/pdt/), which I did, but if I create a new PHP Project, there is no option to make a "new Zend project" or something like this, so I kept on searching, and found this:

https://code.google.com/p/zend-sdk/wiki/GettingStartedTutorialInEclipse

which absolutely had no visible effect on the GUI of Eclipse. I don't know if it even worked, but it doesn't look like on the screenshots at all. On the screenshots of this projects you can see that there is a option while creating a new PHP project called "Zend Framework default project structure". Below I attached a screenshot of my "new PHP project" dialog.

[image]

So, my question is... Did I do something wrong? Or is there currently no proper Zend integration in Eclipse?

Also I want you to know that I need Eclipse for many other programming languages, so I don't really want to have a IDE for each language and it would be nice to get it to work on Eclipse somehow...

I am using Eclipse Juno... If I forgot to provide further information please let me know so I can hand them in later.

I appreciate every kind of help... Thanks in advance

Comment: I had trouble including properly zend project in zend studio, my solution was to create a Void project then copy "normal" project inside, that produce something little "ugly" but working. hope this comment helps you.

Comment: Hi Timmz, thanks for your answer. I will keep that in mind if everything else will not work

Comment: Probably you were deceived. Zend-sdk has no such function. It is a feature of Zend Studio. See http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-work-with-svn-and-zend-framewrok-in-eclipse-pdt/ and note that it is too much OLD story.

Comment: I have now downloaded Eclipse for PHP developers. In this version, the code completion works, but I still have no idea why it won't work on my actual Eclipse where I installed the Eclipse PDT... It's kind of annoying that I know have to maintain two different versions of Eclipse...